# Applications not installed but still taking up phone memory

Tags: internal-storage, samsung-galaxy-ace

I have Samsung Galaxy Ace, rooted.

Today, I tried to install an application. It didn't install, but my phone memory reduced by around 10mb. Again, I tried to install another app, and the memory reduced by 12mb.

The apps are not installed. Their icons are not showing in the phone, but they are taking away space. Please help.

Answer (score 1):

If an installation fails, the downloaded `.apk` might still be left in `/data/local` (where the Playstore app downloads it to). In that case, a simple boot should clear it up.

As your device is rooted, you also could use a file manager to check that location, and manually delete the corresponding file.

One more hint: To avoid the "insufficient memory" / "insufficient storage" error (see: [insufficient-memory](/questions/tagged/insufficient-memory), hover you mouse over the tag and select the "info" link for more details), which also might be responsible for failed installations, you will need at least 25MB free space on "internal storage" / "phone storage" (that is, this amount should be available when the installation has finished).

Answer (score 0):

Try to clear your cache using an application like [History Eraser](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=mobi.infolife.eraser) and to reboot all running applications using an application like [Fast Reboot](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.greatbytes.fastreboot#?t=W251bGwsMSwxLDIxMiwiY29tLmdyZWF0Ynl0ZXMuZmFzdHJlYm9vdCJd). This usually solves the problem. Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

Remove the partially installed application by using a File Explorer software

go to  0/Android/obb/ look for the file partially installed

This was found out by self diagnosis.

Comment: OP states that "phone memory" was reduced. Your answer refers to *shared storage", i.e. sd card.